# How to get the CheckBox's, 'selected' attribute to trigger it's select method [SAPUI5]

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have a Table of five rows, with a label + CheckBox. When the CheckBox is selected manually(which triggers the selection event handler), it does color the whole row **grey**, and deselecting it leads to the removal of the color. If it's done via property binding on `selected` by the model, it doesn't trigger the selection event handler `onCheckBoxSelection` and the row color doesn't change.

```
<CheckBox selected="{= ${modelExample>State} === 1}" enabled="true" select="onCheckBoxSelection"/>
```

**Question**: How to trigger the event handler `onCheckBoxSelection` via the property binding on `selected` so that the color changes when the checkbox is selected?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a new function with all the logic you currently use to change the row color. Your EventHandler `onCheckBoxSelected` should then use the newly created function.

Then you can use the Model event [propertyChange](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model%23events/propertyChange). Create a new EventHandler e.g. `onPropertyChange` and call the newly created function from there.

```
onInit: function() {
    // attach the event handler to the model
    this.getView().getModel("modelExample").attachPropertyChange(this.onPropertyChange.bind(this));
},

onCheckBoxSelected: function(oEvent) {
    // call the newly created function
    this._handleSelectionChange(...);
},

onPropertyChange: function(oEvent) {
    // only call the new selection change function if the correct property is changed
    if (oEvent.getParameter("path") === "State") {
        this._handleSelectionChange(...);
    }
},

_handleSelectionChange: function(...) {
    // your code to change the row color
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I believe there is a bit of misunderstanding. I am loading an the model, which does already have the property 'State' with a value, that does all the selection. I do not intend on changing any properties/values.